# How to load React-select Async with initial options for edit item function when using a search API?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using React-Select's Async Select to implement a dropdown where the user will be able to search through a large amount of data. They will see the employee's name when they're searching and they can select multiple employees.

React-select will get the data by using a search API that I have and will insert the query behind by using this method:

```
const loadOptions = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://example.com/search_user?value=${query}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        const results = data.Result;

        if (results === 'No result found.') {
            return [];
        }

        return results;
    };
```

What I want to get is the employee ID and their full name, then post both of these info to an API after the user submitted the form.

All these work perfectly but now I want to implement an **edit function** where the user can edit the `Group Members` that have been saved into the DB and created.

So naturally I will need to load the `react-select`'s Async dropdown with the initial options, but I have no idea how to load the initial options when I'm using a search API that only will get a certain list of results after I typed something.

I want something like this when the user clicks on edit, which will show the saved employee's name (could be single or multi options selected) from the DB:
[image]

Here is the codesandbox for reference but I'm only using a fake API link:

[image: Edit strange-resonance-l631s]

Edit:

**For @Pitter's reference:**
[image]

**Latest update:**
I tried using the `value` options as mentioned by Pitter, but somehow the input's options is not changing even when I tried to deselect or clear the options and when I tried to search and select a new option.

**Final update**
Finally I got it working! All I need was to set the `value` props/component to a state and have a handleChange method for the `onChange` props/component to change the value's state. It actually works as the same way with the usual react-select's `Select`.

Below is the code that I've used:

```
// Creating a state for the selected options
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('')

// To set/load the initial value that is saved for the current item to edit/manage
useEffect(() => {
    // Your code to get the initial values, then set it to the state that you've created
   setSelectedOption(initial)
}, [modalInfo]);

// A handle change method to change the selected value/options
const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
     setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
};

// Then all you need is the onChange method to use the handleChange and 
// having the value set to the state that you've created
return (
        <AsyncSelect
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={selectedOption}
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            cacheOptions
            defaultOptions
            isMulti
            components={animatedComponents}
            getOptionLabel={(e) => e.fullname}
            getOptionValue={(e) => e.empId}
            onInputChange={(value) => setQuery(value)}
        />
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "DefaultOption"? I think you can provide your data to this option. Docs: https://react-select.com/async

Comment: @Pitter I have not tried the "defaultOptions", I will try to look into it for now.

Comment: @Pitter Unforunately, I still can't make it work for my scenario after reading through the documentation.

Comment: @Lance sandbox link helped me a lot. Ty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was reading the issues on ReactSelect github and found the solution.
You need to pass the object in the "value". Take a look in the example below.

```
<AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        value = {1} // this won't work
        value = {{value: 1, label: "black"}}
        loadOptions={promiseOptions}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
/>
```

Reference: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3761

Comment: But what I need is to cater for the case of a multi-selection too, also if I use this method, it will show an empty option instead (I posted the screenshot in my original post), I think this is because there's no option list yet since I didn't type anything to query and search from my API.

Comment: okay, finally I get the value that you mentioned to work, but when I tried to deselect the options, it won't work (the option still stays there), and if I tried to search and select a new option, my onChange => setGroupMembers's state shows that it's added, but the option itself doesn't show up in the select. I've updated the code in my sandbox to reflect this.

Comment: Great! Now I think you need to add this default values as the initial value in your options. I will try a here and post the code

Comment: I've finally got it working, it's because I haven't got the ```value``` set to a state and also I need to have a ```handleChange``` method to change the value's state, it's actually the same with implementing the usual react-select's ```Select```.

Comment: Great! Congrats. It is all working?

Comment: Yeah, it's working as intended now!

Comment: Please mark this answer as "accepted" (tick icon) if it has solved your question.